# How to create an out-of-office message using java

Tags: exchange-server, ewsjavaapi

Is it possible to create a out-of-office message with a start and end date, over any java framework like ewsjavaapi?

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the latest code on our github project.  The method is available on the ExchangeService:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/core/ExchangeService.java#L2663

The signature of the method looks as follows:

public void setUserOofSettings(String smtpAddress, OofSettings oofSettings)